Full Bridge Rectifier - Output Voltage Saturation
I am putting together a full bridge rectifier, see schematics. The load is connected to V+ and V-. Capacitors as low ESR and with respect to the standard formula.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The simulation went as expected. However, when I physically realized this circuit on PCB, something strange happened. Connecting 5 V AC sinusoidal function generator provided about 4 V at output. But when I increased the amplitude (peak-to-peak voltage) of input signal, the voltage at ouput did not grow "linearly" and instead started to saturate. For example, for 10 V at input, the output voltage was only 6.5 V. I returned back to the simulation and tried it again, but nothing strange occured.
I measured the ouput voltage with oscilloscope with input impedance set to 1 MOhm. Am I missing something? I am adding the layout of my bridge rectifier.

EDIT:
Board schematic.


Do you have any load connected? Or just signal generator, bridge with unknown diodes and six capacitors with unknown capacitance and voltage? That's not what you simulated then. Can your generator output such amplitude? Also did you short out one diode with signal generator and scope grounds like many do and don't realize it? Is the capacitor polarity correct? I see positive diode output going to DC output negative terminal and maybe negative on caps. You need to show the schematics of the board.

Please add to the question: capacitor voltage rating, oscilloscope screens for input and output measurements (not at the same time, unless you have isolated probes). Double check capacitor polarities (in the board, they are inverted).

1/ I connected the signal generator to the input and the oscilloscope to the output.
2/The model used for diodes in simulation is 1N4007 (if needed, I can include the model's picture). I did not have an exact model of the capacitor. I measured it with an LCR meter, and I used the measured capacitance and ESR in the simulation.
3/ Signal generator connected directly to the oscilloscope input resulted in desired performance. 10 V set at the output of the generator was nearly 10 V at the display of the oscilloscope (9.9xx volts).
4/ Can you please elaborate on the "short out one diode"?

If your signal generator and scope share a ground, you shorted the rectifier. Draw the complete schematic with both sides grounded and you will see it. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/727135/194393

"I did not have an exact model of the capacitor." At least check the voltage ratings and polarities because the PCB is inverted.

4/ contd. I connected the generator to the input port (the left connector on the PCB) and the oscilloscope to the output port (the right connector on the PCB). No other adjustments were made.
5/ I am aware of the polarity of the output. I made a mistake with it. I desoldered the components to connect it so the positive output is on +. I think that all capacitors are connected in the correct way. When I measured the output capacitance of the circuitry, I got the value I was expecting.
6/ During the measurement solved the polarity issue by reverting OSC probes (osc+ to V-, and osc- to V+).

@devnull The Voltage rating of the capacitor is 63 V. All capacitors are connected, as you see them in the PCB drawing (+ wire connected in the top hole, - wire connected in the bottom hole). If this results in reversed polarity, I can try to repair this. I am afraid I cannot provide an oscilloscope screen soon. For the next few days, I will not be in proximity of any measurement tool.

What’s the source you are using to power it?

@winny, It will be connected to a small voltage generator. Similar to this one. https://www.printables.com/model/658157-hand-crank-generator

Ok, it solves half the problem. It is isolated. You just can't measure both sides (before and after the rectifier) at the same time.

Yes like I suspected, the diodes are in wrong polarity.
The electrolytic capacitors do not handle negative polarity well and will leak current, sometimes very heavily, in reverse direction.
The 50 ohm output impedance of signal generator limits current so because caps leak so much current the generator cannot charge the caps to full voltage and even if it could the caps would leak current and discharge while the diodes do not conduct.
And it may still be that your scope and signal generator short out V- and GND.

Is it possible to solve this issue by reverting the polarity of all diodes?

@HumphreyAppleby Yes. Or all the capacitors. Any way that results in positive output from diodes going to positive capacitor terminals will do. You can decide what to do with the output connector if you want to swap it too.


Can you please elaborate on the "short out one diode"

If the scope and signal generator share a ground, this happens even if you don't measure input and output at the same time:


All capacitors are connected, as you see them in the PCB drawing (+ wire connected in the top hole, - wire connected in the bottom hole). If this results in reversed polarity

Yes, the polarities in the PCB are inverted. When you remove the capacitors to correct this, check if they were not damaged due to the polarity inversion (or, even better, replace them).
These are the cathode and anode terminals:

Source
V+ and V- are inverted (in the full schematics and the PCB, compare with the symbols in the first one).

Is there some way how I can uncouple the grounds of the generator and the oscilloscope

If both are connected to the earth pin at the power plugs, no direct way to change this (don't cut them). A few options:
If you need simultaneous measurement (just the scope ground clips will short both sides):

4 channel scope with a single ground at the input and differential measurement at the rectified side;
isolated probe(s)

Without simultaneous measurement:

get a scope or signal generator which can be powered by an isolated power supply
measure the rectified side in differential mode, with ground clips at the input
use an isolation transformer to float one of the devices
forget about the signal generator and just use a transformer as the input of the rectifier


Is there some way how I can uncouple the grounds of the generator and the oscilloscope? I assume that as they are both connected to the network, they are connected. Is that true?

Use a battery powered oscilloscope as the one of the easiest ways to "float" the oscilloscope. Or use a transformer as the source for the rectifier.
You are fortunate that you used a signal generator to initially power the circuit, in the real application, the current flow through reverse biased capacitors fed from a transformer might cause enough heating to cause the capacitors to rupture and vent an unpleasant smelling steam. Larger capacitors have designed rupture points, the cases of smaller capacitors can leave the circuit board as though fired from an air rifle.

So, would be ok to measure the output of the rectifier with a battery-powered voltmeter? The input would be still connected to the signal generator. I wanted to observe if the output is smooth enough, but I think that knowing that the output is correct is sufficient for me.
